# Relative path for Folder.Files

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016, m

I have an Excel file, and in the same folder I have a folder with CSV files I want to include. Using the From Folder query thing, the first step will give the following query:

```
= Folder.Files("D:\OneDrive\Documents\Health\Concept2")
```

Now, this path will not be the same on my laptop for example, but the Excel file will always be in the Health directory...

I get an error if I try to just pass a relative path to `Folder.Files`, but is there a way to work around this? A fancy function? Some variable or thing I don't know about because I'm a total newb in this area?

---

**Attempt 1**

```
= Folder.Files(".\Concept2")
= Folder.Files("Concept2")
```

❌*DataFormat.Error: The supplied folder path must be a valid absolute path.*

---

**Attempt 2**

```
= Folder.Files(Activeworkbook.Path & "\Concept2")
```

❌ *Expression.Error: The name 'Activeworkbook.Path' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.*

Comment: have you tried `= Folder.Files("Concept2")`?

Comment: @AverageWorker Yes, tried that one too 

Answer (score 3):

*As far as I know* you can't make a relative path reference entirely inside Power Query itself. What you CAN do however is setup a relative path reference inside your excel file, then load this into Power Query.

So setup a tab in your Excel file and make a one cell table with the formula

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"))-1)&"Concept2\"
```

To get your relative directory reference. Add this table into Power Query, and then you can get the relative directory for you file query like

```
Folder.Files(DirectoryQuery{0}[ColumnName])
```

Where "DirectoryQuery" is the name of the query created from your table and "ColumnName" is the name of the column in the table ({0} references the first row in the table).

Comment: Also see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Power-Query-Source-from-Relative-Paths/td-p/206150

Answer (score -2):

```
= Folder.Files(Activeworkbook.Path & "\Concept2")
```

Comment: *Expression.Error: The name 'Activeworkbook.Path' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.* 

Comment: oh - I thought you were using VBA within Excel. I'm not familiar with PowerQuery. Sorry.